# Data input from one database to a remote database

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a website for an e-commerce purpose. On the main page there will be a permanent text-block or a featured article, which is going to display information about latest money transactions.

For security reasons I want to hide the source where this information is coming from. So I decided to create 2 sites:

**a) "Main Site" (MS):** will be a fully custom site with an engine, which will be responsible to deal with and handle financial transactions. This site will contain all financial data and will be known/accessible only for limited people.

**b) "Customer Site" (CS):** will provide basic information along with "Latest transaction" page.

Main point is that "Latest transaction" on CS will be just a static copy of "latest" table in MS database and will not be available to be tracked back, as it will be uploaded/input from MS side each time when there is a new transaction. I presume that even if someone dumps the CS database, he/she will only be able to get a plain-text, without reaching the core database in MS. Because data input will be one-way from MS to CS.

*Here is the draft scheme how I assume it to be, but don't know how to do:*

- Database-to-Database: to write a custom php file, which will be triggered after a new transaction and copy "latest" table values from MS database to a "latest" table in CS database.

**Thanking in advance for any ideas, guides and especially for inputs.**

Comment: You could store data in Database one, then have a column named Moved set to default 0 for example... Then run a cronjob, to move all data which is set to 0 over to the remote database then set the column for the moved data to 1; which wont be moved again

Comment: @DarylGill, for sorting out moved and new data I'm doing almost as you mention. My question was about transferring this data.

Comment: If your sites are running Linux, you could run a cronjob which has a  every 5 minute trigger, which will move data across

Comment: Yes, my hosting company offers Linux servers, but for security reasons it doesn't allow remote database connection. So I'm trying to get any other workaround from professionals on this topic. I'm good at SQL or Linux, but I'll try to deliver my idea in a way that I can. How to do this:

copy "\MS\database\latest\*.*" "\CS\database\latest\*.*"

Answer (score 0):

If both db's are sql server, give MS permission to write to CS.  Then write a trigger on MS that populates CS according to your requirements.

php involvement is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, both db's are same sql. Is it possible to give a separate permission to MS, so that it can write only to "latest" table instead of giving 'root' access?